# Pusher and laravel echo too slow or something wrong with my code?

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, pusher, laravel-echo

I am using Laravel 5.3 on homestead. Here's the code that I am using for broadcasting an event through pusher and laravel echo, to notify the users of a new message in real time -

```
 class NewMessageReceived implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    public $message;
    public $user;
    public $sender;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Message $message, User $user)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->sender = \Auth::user();
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('user.'. $this->user->id);
    }

}
```

Here's the code that calls this event-

```
     try{
             $m = $privateChat->messages()->save($m);
                if( isset(Auth::user()->guide))
                   event ( new NewMessageReceived( $m, $m->messageable->tourist->user ));
                 else
                   event ( new NewMessageReceived( $m, $m->messageable->guide->user ));

                 return $m;
            }
            catch(Exception $e){
                return $e;
            }
```

There's an ajax call in vue, which receives the response generated by above code i.e $m .

The problem is if I use the code below instead of the above code, response is recieved at least 5 times faster. I just need to remove the event-firing part to make it run faster (which is not desired, since I want to update user in real time)-

```
    try{
         $m = $privateChat->messages()->save($m);

             return $m;
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            return $e;
        }
```

It would be helpful if you could help me spot the reason behind this behaviour and how can I make it all happen in real time, instead of the delay existing now.

Answer (score 4):

You should change `ShouldBroadcast` to `ShouldBroadcastNow`. That will solve the problem with delay.

Comment: Thanks, After the change `ShouldBroadcast` to `ShouldBroadcastNow`  it is fast now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Move your if logic to event Class

```
class NewMessageReceived implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    public $message;
    public $user;
    public $sender;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Message $message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;

        $this->user = isset(Auth::user()->guide)) ? $message->messageable->tourist->user : $this->user = $message->messageable->guide->user;
        $this->sender = \Auth::user();
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('user.'. $this->user->id);
    }

}
```

Now your event call.

```
$m = $privateChat->messages()->save($m);
event(new NewMessageReceived($m));
return $m;
```

Comment: That's nice for refactoring the existing code. Thanks! But the concern expressed above still remains unresolved. I am not using any queue for the above broadcast, and even if I configure a queue driver(database), the broadcast is not queued and fires off synchronously. It's against the instructions provided in the documentation. Maybe it's also the reason why it's slow as well. I am after a fix to this issue at the moment.